# How to make sure no Carriage returns are added to Notepad++ documents?

Tags: notepad++

How to make sure no Carriage returns are added to Notepad++ documents?

I don't want Notepadd++ to add carriage returns (`cr` characters) to any of my documents. Can I prevent it adding them to any document whatsoever?

Edit: I mean to also auto-remove them from any existing document I edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Settings > Preferences -> New Documents -> Format, You want the unix/osx radio checked

To change existing documents you can use replace under the search menu, the find term would be "\r\n" then replace it with "\n" make sure search mode is set to extended in the bottom left box in the replace window.

Comment: Hi, can you please edit the answer and add a note about converting existing file to Unix as well?

Comment: @Benia in Notepad++: Select Edit Tab, EOL conversion, format to Unix.